# Select categories from cat_table where main_table items with that category not empty

Tags: mysql, select, join, group-by

I couldn't think of the proper way to phrase this and maybe if I knew the correct phrase I could Google it properly but as of yet I am struggling.

I have two tables: categories, directory

On the page where the user selects the category I would like to only show categories where the directory items with that category exist.

I wondered if I could do this with a join and tried

```
SELECT
wedding_directory_cats.id,
wedding_directory_cats.name,
wedding_directory.id AS d_id
FROM wedding_directory_cats
JOIN wedding_directory ON wedding_directory.category = wedding_directory_cats.id
```

But this is returning the category for each directory item, so I end up with the same category more than once. Just as I am writing this I'm starting to think I could use GROUP BY at the end but this still means it has to return them all first and then GROUP BY, is that inefficient or is there a better way of doing something like this? Any answers appreciated

Comment: Explain with sample data and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT wdc.id, wdc.name, wd.id AS d_id
FROM wedding_directory_cats wdc
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, category FROM wedding_directory GROUP BY category) wd ON wdc.id = wd.category ;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT wdc.id, wdc.name, GROUP_CONCAT(wd.id) AS d_id
FROM wedding_directory_cats wdc
INNER JOIN wedding_directory wd ON wdc.id = wd.category 
GROUP BY wd.category;
```